# How give a new view access to a BigQuery dataset via API (patch)

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a dataset in BigQuery with some views permissioned to it.

Via the API, I want to permission a new view for that dataset. Using the [patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets#resource-representations) method:

```
...
#permission the view
dataset_ref = {'datasetId': 'dataset_b', 'projectId': 'foo'}
update = {'access': [
          {
            "view": {
               "projectId": 'foo',
                "datasetId": 'dataset_b',
                "tableId": 'v_test'
             }
           }
        ]}
datasets = service.datasets()
datasets.patch(body=update, **dataset_ref).execute()
```

But, instead of **adding** the new view to the list of permissioned views, it replaces them all. I thought only the [update](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets/update) method would do this. From the **update** docs:

> Warning: The specified access list completely overwrites the existing
>   access list. If you specify an empty access list, you will revoke
>   access to everyone except yourself; you cannot remove all owners from
>   a dataset.

From the patch docs:

> Updates information in an existing dataset. The update method replaces
>   the entire dataset resource, whereas the patch method only replaces
>   fields that are provided in the submitted dataset resource. This
>   method supports patch semantics.

Is it possible to just add a new view using the patch method?

(I know it's possible to provide multiple views in the patch request, but that would mean having to query the dataset first for all its existing permissions and then adding the new one - messy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update method replaces the entire dataset resource, whereas the patch method only replaces fields that are provided in the submitted dataset resource.

The key above is - the patch method only replaces fields that are provided
This means that access property will be REPLACED - the whole access property (with exception of case when you provide empty list - because at least one owner must be present at any time)

So, unfortunatelly you need to provide whole acl list by first retrieving current acl and adding new entries to it

Comment: Bummer. I wonder if it's worth requesting that functionality. It's really awkward having to make make an additional call to fetch all the ACLs and then append, and then send them all back.

Comment: Consider how many different changes you can potentially make in one shot. change access, revoke access, add new access and all those for multiple items. I think current approach makes it simple - you load existing acl  - you do all needed changes and you submit back new acl. it makes sense to me (as it is now)

Comment: at the same time - interesting - Storage Team approached this differently - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/bucketAccessControls - there might be a reason for this

Comment: Sure, but what if I only want to add a single new ACL. Then it's an additional network request to first fetch the existing ACLs, modify and then patch. Feels somewhat clumsy to me. Nice spot with GCS!

Comment: sure - understood  - there is always balance between this and that to consider while designing api. most likely this was considered by google team. in my practice acl is not something you do as frequently as other data centric apis, so I never felt this specific need

Comment: Agree that mucking around with ACLs is not a common API use case. That said however, the more we integrate BigQuery into all our distributed business units, the more need we have for modifying the ACLs on datasets. Anyway, I think it's worth asking for it. Worst they can say is "go get stuffed"!

Comment: absolutelly agree with you. just wanted to share my thoughts with you vs. just say obvious "yes" :o)

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across the same issue and spent some time looking for the answer on how to update the access entry as I was getting the "Cannot remove all owners from a dataset" message.

This doesn't answer your patch question, but provides a work around to the error and hopefully saves others some time.

the [updating-datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets) docs resolved my issue but yes, it grabs all entries appends and updates them all.